# Java regex not working - string split

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have a string variable and want to extract a value from it.

```
String LB0001 = "LB0001"; 
String[] splitString = LB0001.split("LB(.*)");
```

What I was expecting is that `splitString` would contain two values, `["LB0001",["0001"]]`. However the result is null. Why? I have checked the regex and seems to be correct.

I want to extract "0001". I can do it using other ways, but would like to know what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `split` method will split where ever the regular expression provided matches. In your case, the expression `LB(.*)` matches the provided string completely, thus you get nothing back.

If you want to get the number part, you can split on anything which is not a digit, like so: `.split("\\D")`. This should get you 1 element which contains `0001`.

EDIT: If you want *anything* after `LB` you would need to use the `Pattern` and `Matcher` class. So basically something like so:

```
String str = "LB0001";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("LB(.*?)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while(m.find())
    System.out.println(m.groups(1));
```

The above will make use of regular expressions to look for any text which follows `LB`. I have changed it from `.*` to `.*?` in case you have something like so: `LB001LB333`. The extra `?` makes the expression non greedy.

Comment: Thank you. I part understand however, i am using http://myregexp.com/ to test my regex. When testing on the site, the regex is split into two groups group 1, is the full string match and group 2 is anything after "LB" .Is there a function in java that would give me a similar result?

Comment: Thank you, i ended up doing something similar. Have marked as solution

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String LB0001 = "LB0001"; 
String[] splitStringAlpha = LB0001.split("[a-zA-Z]+");
System.out.println(splitStringAlpha[0]); 
String[] splitStringNum = LB0001.split("\\D");
System.out.println(splitStringNum[0]);
```

this should give you

```
LB
0001
```

Comment: \w stands for "word character", usually [A-Za-z0-9_], so `LB0001.split("\\W"); `return LB0001